# OpenGL quake 3 shader file for objects (for trees)

Tags: opengl, quake3, model-loader

I decided to add to my game few trees, I already quake 3 model loader (md3) its for characters and method for texture drawing is store in *.ini file. I found a package of trees in MD3 and I have no problem with loading model alone, but there is a *.shader file and i have no idea how to load it to draw texture properly.

Tree pack: http://www.custommapmakers.org/wiki/index.php/Models:GR_Trees_set

I do not have to use exactly this format, I can write another loader, but trees in *.obj or 
.3ds look even harder

Comment: @EricB Quake 3 shader files are something else..

Answer (score 1):

The quake 3 "shader" is basically just a description of the rendering parameters, and has little or nothing to do with opengl shaders. Here's an example from your tree package:

```
models/mapobjects/GR_trees/tree6
{
    cull none
    nopicmip

    {
        map models/mapobjects/GR_trees/tree6.tga
        alphaFunc GE128
        depthWrite
        rgbGen vertex
    }
}
```

Many of the things listed there are pretty obvious - disable clipping, use tree6.tga as texture, have depth write enabled.. as for the rest, you might want to look up the reference:

http://toolz.nexuizninjaz.com/shader/